# C#, DataGridView: Cannot update database after importing data from Excel

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, insert-update

I have a DataGridView & 3 buttons, Submit (submit inserted/changed data), Load (Load data from database), Import (Import data from Excel to DataGridView).

If I do not import from Excel, everything is fine, it loads from DB and inserts/updates changes done.
But once I import data from Excel, it stops updating to DB.
I understand that I am doing smth wrong with DataTable (dtPO), please help to fix it. Since morning I am trying without success.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
SqlDataAdapter da;
SqlCommandBuilder scb;
DataTable dtPO;
```

Load Button

```
private void btnPOLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Descriptions, SAPcode, Unit, [HW/SW/Service], POno, Currency, [PO. Qty], Rate FROM POitems", con);
    da.Fill(dtPO);
    dgvPO.DataSource = dtPO;
}
```

Submit Button

```
private void btnPOSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
  da.Update(dtPO);       
}
```

Import Button

```
private void btnImportPO_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
   System.Data.DataSet DtSet;
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;

   OpenFileDialog choofdlog = new OpenFileDialog();
   choofdlog.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xls, *.xlsx)|*.xls; *.xlsx";
   choofdlog.FilterIndex = 1;
   choofdlog.Multiselect = false;
   string sFileName;

   if (choofdlog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
       sFileName = choofdlog.FileName;

       MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + sFileName + "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
       MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet2$]", MyConnection);
       MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Net-informations.com");
       DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
       MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);

       dtPO = DtSet.Tables[0];
       dgvPO.DataSource = dtPO;
       MyConnection.Close();
   }

}
```

Comment: Looks like you're closing the connection in the Import method: MyConnection.Close();     Show where you are opening the connection so we can determine that it is being opened correctly before click handlers are called.

Comment: +1 to what mjw said...additionally, after you open the connection, surround your command with using(MyConnection){} that way the connection is properly taken care of automatically.

Comment: in btnImportPO_Click() connection is to Excel file only. Connection is open, I put DataSet to another control which loads data. I cannot find where it is opening connection. As I said, if I insert data manually to DataGridView, it saves to DB

Comment: Found it, connection opens in form designer.  internal global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection Connection {
            get {
                if ((this._connection == null)) {
                    this.InitConnection();
                }
                return this._connection;
            }

Comment: Checked for DB connection as well, it is open.   try
            {
                if (con != null && con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    con.Open();
                scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
                da.Update(dtPO);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.Source);
            }